# rsync doesn't follow the exclude-from list of files and directories

Tags: rsync, exclude

I am trying to make the backup of my files to an external HD via rsync, I have been struggling to use the exclude-from as it doesn't behave as I think it should.

My home (home/user) contains the following (simplified)

```
─directory/
─.cache/
─VirtualBox VM/
─backup_system/
  ├── copy_home_to_hdd.sh
  └── exclude
```

exclude contains the following (simplified)

```
VirtualBox VM
.cache
```

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -avh -zl=0 --info=progress --exclude-from=exclude /home/user/ /media/user/HOMES/work/
```

I am launching the script from the backup_system directory and from home (./backup_system/copy_home_to_hdd.sh when doing this I replace the exclude-from to include that directory). I would expect rsync to copy the files and leaving a destination like

```
─directory/
─backup_system/
  ├── copy_home_to_hdd.sh
  └── exclude
```

However, it ignores the exclude list and copies everything.

Comment: What is the output of `file exclude`? Does it mention CRLF?

Comment: ~/backup_system> file exclude 
exclude: ASCII text